# How do I use the GPU debugger for a mixed mode managed/native level editor application?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, gpu, direct3d

I have a C#/.net level editor that renders the level into a sub-window via my game engine in a native C++ .dll (D3D12). When I start GPU diagnostics via Alt-F5 the application runs but the level no longer renders into the window. I therefore can't capture any frames. No errors are reported.

Is it possible to perform GPU debugging in this context? If so what settings do I need to allow this to work?

Thanks

Comment: If your app doesn't render to a traditional HWND, CoreWindow, or Composition (XAML) swap chain, it might confuse the capture system.  Have you tried running the [dxcap tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn774939.aspx) manually?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am rendering to an HWND provided by winforms. I ran the dxcap command but the result was the same as through Visual Studio. The level editor ran but nothing rendered into the level window.